# Matrix differential problem

Tags: calculus, matrices

How to derive the Jacobian and Hessian matrices of 
$f(X)=\textrm{tr}\left[(R+XX^H)^{-1}\right]$? where $X$ is a matrix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $x=X?$ Is $H$ hermitian adjoint?

Comment: And is there any relationship between $R$ and $X?$

Comment: Sorry, $x=X$, there is no relationship between $R$ and $X$.

Comment: @meo, are $R,X$ real matrices ? Is $R$ a symmetric or hermitian matrix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\boldsymbol{A \equiv (R+X\cdot X^H)^{-2}}$

Then the derivative you seek is 
$$\boldsymbol{{\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{X}}}= -(A+A^H)\cdot X}$$

This was result was obtained by applying the chain rule to this nice formula for the derivative of the trace of a matrix function:
$$\boldsymbol{{\frac{\partial{\,{\rm tr}(G(Y))}}{\partial{Y}}}=g(Y)^H}$$

Where $g(s)$ is the scalar derivative of $G(s)$, i.e. 
$$g(s) = {\frac{dG(s)}{ds}}$$

Get started by identifying
$\boldsymbol{f(X) = {\rm\,tr}(G(Y))}$

with 
$\boldsymbol{Y \equiv (R+X\cdot X^H)}$ and $G(s) \equiv s^{-1}$

Comment: I have figured it out, but still thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $R > XX^H$ (meaning, the spectral radius of $XX^HR^{-1}$ is strictly less than one. Let $Y= XX^H.$ Then, we can expand the inverse in a power series in $Y,$ and by linearity of trace compute the derivative of $f$ with respect to $Y.$ Now, use the chain rule to compute the derivative of $f$ as a function of $X.$

Comment: That would probably work. But isn't there some well-known results dealing with matrix derivative? Like $D_X(AXB))=B^H\otimes A$.